# How do I create dot texture to use for halftone in Blender's Compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes, procedural

I want to create a halftone effect in the Blender's Compositor, and for that, I require a dot texture that can be easily achieved through the voronoi texture node but not through the voronoi texture that I get in the property bar in Blender.

Voronoi texture node that works for any material. I want the same effect in Blender's Compositor:

[image: Voronoi texture node that works for any material. I want the same effect in Blender's Compositor]

So how should I go about creating a dot texture to use in Blender's Compositor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create this in the Compositor procedurally. You can bake the texture from the material nodes and then just use that image. It would be better to keep it 32bit EXR.

[image]

[image]

Then you can save it, load it to the Compositor and tile it there:

[image]

[image]

Comment: OK, it seems my math for aligning the dots to pixels is broken, but that  wasn't the question.